# Labels with buffers creates bloated PDF file in Composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, pdf

I know this question has appeared before, but the earlier questions appear to be linked to the old labeling engine. I'm running qgis 2.0, which I thought uses the new-generation labeling engine. In my map there are three labels (not three layers, but just three labels) that are buffered. The pdf file grows from 1MB to 18MB by turning on buffering.

Am I wrong in thinking that 2.0 uses the new labeling engine? The rest of the team I'm working with is on 2.0 and moving everyone is not easy for a variety of reasons.

Comment: I believe the new labelling engine generates only rasterised output, based on http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3975 still being open.

Comment: There are some new options in 2.4 http://anitagraser.com/2014/09/20/labels-as-text-in-svg-exports/ but I'm not sure how the affect PDF size.

Comment: @BradHards - The pdf file does appear to be rasterised, not vector output. This only deepens the mystery as to why the buffer around characters increases the file size, since the raster size (modulo compression issues) shouldn't really change that much, no matter how the buffer is created. The SVG is also huge (as big as the pdf with the buffers), but doesn't seem to change much with the buffers.